# How to use Hive with HDFS?

Tags: hive, hdfs

when we create internal table in hive and the destination path for data to table is on HDFS and when i drop that table will the data from HDFS for that table will going to be deleted?

I haven't tried this yet can some please help me

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, if you have hive managed table then data files and folders are created and deleted with create and drop tables respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a managed table, then yes.
If it is an external table, if the Table Property `external.table.purge=true` is set then yes, else No